# Multi exclude in rosbag record?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
When rosbag is used as follows

```
$ rosbag record -a -x "/usb_cam/(.*)"
```

how can I add more exclusion?
For example, I would like to exclude

```
/usb_cam/*
```

and

```
/usb_cam_repub/theora/*
```

It should be simple, but I'm not familiar with regex.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35888/multi-exclude-in-rosbag-record?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-08-16**:
It's not clear to me what you want to achieve, but as I also encountered the problem (I want to record everything, except raw and compressed camera image topics), I posted a bug report: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the following:

```
rosbag record -a -O data.bag -x "/usb_cam/(.*)|/usb_cam_repub/theora/(.*)"
```

---

Originally posted by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) with karma: 230 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11